# The problem of analyzing a string and searching

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I want to write code that takes a string of text from the user and shows the number of characters and the number of words using the .find () function.  then takes a word from user and Search the text and show the position of the word. I'm in trouble now, please help me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   char quit;
    int word=0;
    string txt;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, txt);
    cout << "The number of characters in the string is:" << txt.length() << endl;
    while(string txt != NULL)
    {   if(txt.find(" "))
            ++word;
    }
    cout<<"wors is "<<word;
    while(quit!='q')
    {

        cout<<"wors is ";
        cin>>search;
        cout<<"Enter(c)if you want to continue, and enter(q)if you want quic:";
        cin>>quit;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(string txt != NULL) {   if(txt.find(" ")) ++word; }` -- What if there are multiple consecutive spaces?  You have the issue even if you fix the `string txt != NULL` part of the code.

Comment: The [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns the position in the string, if found; otherwise returns `std::string::npos`.  Both values could be considered as `true`; however, if the string starts with a space, the position will be 0 which evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of extracting words.  There are many other methods.

```
static const char end_of_word_chars[] = "!?., :\t";
//...
std::string::size_type previous_position = 0;
std::string::size_type position = txt.find_first_of(end_of_word_chars);
while (position != std::string::npos)
{
  std::string word = txt.substr(previous_position, position - previous_position);
  std::cout << word << "\n";
  previous_position = txt.find_first_of(position + 1);
  position = txt.find_first_not_of(end_of_word_chars);
}
```

The above code uses an array of "end of word characters", to denote the end of a word.  The string `txt` is searched from the beginning to find the position of the first character that is in the set of word endinging characters.  In the `while` loop, the spaces or non-word characters are skipped.  And the position of the next "word ending" character is found and the loop may repeat again.

**Edit 1:  String as stream**
Another method is to treat the `txt` as a string stream and use `operator>>` to skip whitespace:

```
std::istringstream text_stream(txt);
std::string word;
while (text_stream >> word)
{
    std::cout << word << "\n";
}
```

One issue with the above code fragment is that it doesn't account for word ending characters that are not spaces or tabs.  So for example, in the text "Yes. I'm Home.", the period is included as part of the "word", such as "Yes." and "Home."